# Blow up of a ODE in finite time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb R), f>0$, $y_0\in\mathbb R$. Look at the ODE $y'(t)=f(y(t)), y(0)=y_0$. Let $(t_-,t_+)$ be the largest interval where a solution of the ODE exists. Show that $\lim_{t\to t_+}y(t)=\infty$.
I tried to use $y(t)=y_0+\int_0^t f(y(s))ds$ or that a solution satisfies $\int_{y_0}^{y(t)}\frac{1}{f(x)}dx=t$ but I think this does not help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y$ were bounded, there would be a limit at $t\to t_+$ if $t_+$ is finite. Then $(t_-,t_+)$ would not be the maximal domain.

If $t_+=\infty$ and $y$ is bounded, then the limit has to be a root of $f$, which contradicts $f>0$.

Comment: That argument is not enough, as can be seen when the condition $f>0$ is dropped (for $f(x) = 0$, the solution of the ODE is $y(t) = y_0$, which does not tend to $\infty$).

Comment: Ok, partially. It was not stated in the question that $t_+$ is finite. But I think it was heavily implied. In a more general formulation, $(t,y(t))$ has to tend to infinity in at least one component for $t\to t_+$.

Comment: I understand the case $t_+<\infty$ but I dont know hoe to prove the case $t_+=\infty$. I think I need the condition $f>0$ @LutzLehmann